# Persistent server that provides input?

Tags: node.js, input, command-line, discord, discord.js

I made a Discord bot in NodeJS using `discord.js`. I want it to be constantly running. So, my idea was to deploy it to something like Heroku. But, I occasionally need to provide input to the program. This program will be getting input from the command-line. Is there some server or PaaS that I can use to constantly host and run my bot? I would prefer it to be free, and I don't really care about how fast it is.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Zeit's Now - [zeit.co/now](https://zeit.co/now) - It is by far the easiest node.js deploy. You literally type 'now' and your application is deployed to a unique URL in under 10 seconds.

Another option can be [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/). It is an open source PaaS by Red Hat based on top of Docker containers and the Kubernetes container cluster manager for enterprise app development.

Hope those will help to run your bot continuously. You can also take input from the command line.